# Headless mode in Api "Dolphin Anty" selenium

Tags: python, selenium, headless, dolphin-browser

I'm using antidetect browser Api "Dolphin anty" with python selenium and I want to enable Headless mode, but in this Api commands `options.headless = True` and `options.addarguments( --headless )` don't work :(

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't work? Does the browser just appear in non-headless mode?

Comment: Yes, starts in normal mode

Answer (score 0):

When you start automation you need to add `"headless": true` as param

```
http://localhost:3001/v1.0/browser_profiles/{browser_id}/start?automation=1&headless=true
```